# Unable to install dash on python 2.7.16

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly-dash

I am using 'pip install dash' on the command line, at first I get an error which tells me to download Visual C++. I follow the lead and download and install Microsoft visual C++

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

Then once again I try by 'pip install dash' and now it fails with below error.

```
_brotli.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'init_brotli' specified multiple times; using first specification
       Creating library bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common\_brotli.lib and object bin\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\c/common\_brotli.exp
    encode.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
    static_dict.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
    backward_references.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64 referenced in function FindMatchLengthWithLimit
    backward_references_hq.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
    compress_fragment.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
    compress_fragment_two_pass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tzcnt_u64
    bin\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_brotli.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\karthik\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I have searched for this type of error and could not find any solution.
Can anyone guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: same error for me too ... any possible resolution ?

Comment: Hi
I was able to overcome this issue when I used the version brotli 1.0.7. You could try as well.

Comment: According to Brotli support group, it is fixed in master and available in version 1.0.10